# How to tie VSTS (aka Azure DevOps) account to Azure Subscription

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I understand how to create a new DevOps project from https://portal.azure.com and I see how that creates a new DevOps organisation or reuses an existing one (scoped to that AzureAD).
A new project is also created as well as an associated WebApps project.

These are my challenges:

1. When one creates a new Project in that DevOps organisation, it doesn't show up for management in https://portal.azure.com. How can one ensure the resources consumed by that project are part of the Azure Subscription to which the parent organisation is tied?  Or is that the default?
2. What is the easiest way of tying existing DevOps organisations and projects to an Azure subscription to allow increasing the default 5 user limit and consuming more pipeline resources?

There doesn't seem to be any documentation anywhere that directly addresses these issues for me.

Comment: It seems I didn't express myself clearly and hence, the question was marked down and voted for closure. @Shamrai actually gave me what I needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use Azure DevOps Organizations to connect your azure subscription with devops account:
[image]

Then you may use users on Azure DevOps from Azure Active Directory and manage billing (get more license): 
[image]

Also you may use DevOps Project wizard to create a team project from a template:

[image]

Additional links:

- [Quickstart: Set up billing for your organization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/billing/set-up-billing-for-your-organization-vs?view=vsts)
- [Azure DevOps Projects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops-project/)
- [Tutorial: Connect your organization to Azure Active Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/connect-organization-to-azure-ad?view=vsts&tabs=new-nav)
- [Quickstart: Pay for more Basic users](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/billing/buy-basic-access-add-users?view=vsts&tabs=new-nav)
- [About access levels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/access-levels?view=vsts)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. I was able to use this to resolve the issue I was having. I have never used the All Services menu option till now. I was actually wondering where the Azure DevOps Organization went to. Now I can add it to a subscription and understand that it must reside in a Resource Group to be managed as per Microsoft's approach to administering Azure.